# Do the contacts on a SIM card and card holder always match?

Tags: surface-mount, sim

I am trying to choose an SMD SIM card holder for my PCB but while doing so noticed a few inconsistencies for the C1-C8 locations on a product's footprint.  It has got me wondering if all SIM cards and holders use the same locations for C1-C8 on their footprints.  Like, for example, is the location of Vcc (C1) standardized for both the card and card holder?

TE Connectivity's 1981959-1 is the component in question.

If I look at the datasheet I find the diagram below for SIM card contacts and corresponding pads on the component's footprint.

If I go on Mouser and download the SamacSYS (2nd image below) footprint I see that the location of C4 is on the back-row of the contact pads instead of on the front with C1-C3.

This has gotten me confused.  I am guessing this is just an error on the SamacSYS footprint.

Can I expect that the SIM card I am using was designed with the SIM card pin assignment below?  That is C1, C2, C3 are Vcc, RST and CLK respectively and so on?

[image: datasheet image]

[image: footprint]

Answer (score 1):

The pad location *on the SIM card* are fixed by ISO, and so their meaning. However how the signals are brought out on the holder is manufacturer dependant and you can't rely on all the holders being compatible. It's possible that there is some popular layout made by many manufacturers but it's not ensured.

If you are worried about errors in the datasheet, ask the manufacturer. It happens sometimes. Most probably they *won't* fix the datasheet for a few years but at least you'll have the right pinout.